# How to set icon size in TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Here is my code:

```
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.mipmap.ic_compass,
        R.mipmap.ic_place,
        R.mipmap.ic_passport,
        R.mipmap.ic_setting
};


...
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
```

The size of icon is according to image size. How could I resize it?

Comment: change height and width from xml..

Comment: try re sizing icon using editors

Comment: set height of tablayout for increase size of icon

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decide to close this question. Since we actually cannot set specific size for icon in TabLayout but padding to it. 
Ref:
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_tab

Answer (score 6):

set icons padding

```
    for (int i = 0; i < tablayout.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        tablayout.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setPadding(10,10,10,10);
    }
```

Comment: What the hell on earth is tablayout.getTabWidget()? It seems that there is none?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use xml for the custom view. Simply create imageview on runtime and add that in tablayout in a particular tab.

```
  ImageView imgView= new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
  imgView.setImageResource(drawableImage);
  imgView.setPadding(10,10,10,10)
  tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(imgView);
```

It will look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change of Icon size  **`android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`**

```
for (int i = 0; i < view_bottom_tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++)
            {
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(60, 60); //set new width & Height
                params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER; //set gravity back to center
                view_bottom_tabLayout.getChildAt(i).setLayoutParams(params);//set ur new params 

            }
```

Comment: I got an NPE at this line: `view_bottom_tabLayout.getChildAt(i).setLayoutParams(params);`

Comment: sure you are using this tabLayout (`android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`) in xml ? and make sure u added your child elements in to the view and use this line after.

Answer (score 0):

To get total control of size I recommend using a custom view to render the tab.

**First create a new layout - named "my_custom_tab" for this example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--Change the width, height, scaleType to whatever you like-->
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

**Now in your code set the custom image**

```
private void setUpTabs (ViewPager viewPager) {
  TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        if (tabs != null) {
            tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

   int tabCount = tabAdapter.getCount(); //Assuming you have already somewhere set the adapter for the ViewPager

            for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {
                TabLayout.Tab tab = tabs.getTabAt(i);
                if (tab != null){
                    ImageView myCustomIcon = (ImageView) LayoutInflater.from(tabs.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_custom_tab, null);

                    /*Here is where to set image if doing it dynamically
                    myCustomIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    */

                    tab.setCustomView(myCustomIcon);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++) {
        LinearLayout tabView = (LinearLayout) ll.getChildAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < tabView.getChildCount(); j++) {
            if (tabView.getChildAt(j) instanceof TextView) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) tabView.getChildAt(j);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.topMargin = 0;
                textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            } else if (tabView.getChildAt(j) instanceof ImageView) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) tabView.getChildAt(j);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = 0;
                imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

one code worked for me, the answer above of Deepak Sachdeva
just i edited it a litlle, try it 100% working
from first i add the tab with custom image

```
    ImageView imgView= new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
      imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
      imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    
    imgView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));

tablayout1.addTab(tablayout1.newTab().setCustomView(imgView));
```

and do that to all your tabs, add them by this way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **android:layout** attribute of `TabItem`. This is the most proper way to achive your desired result:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout="@layout/custom_tab_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_..." />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout="@layout/custom_tab_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_..." />

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Add **custom_tab_item** in layout folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/icon"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp">
</ImageView>
```